# How to rotate a servo continuously?

Tags: arduino-mega

I'm new in robotics. I bought a mini robot ( [Link](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2150619.pdf) ), which i rebuilt a little. Now it has legs and arms. This little robot has 4 little servos ([Link](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/3861-rs001a-dagu-micro-servomotor-8g-1-5kg-cm.html)). There are two wheels attached to two of these servos. I'd like to spin them, so the robot will "roll", but unfortinatly it is trickier than i tought. The servos can rotate in 360 degrees(i can manually turn them), no problem with that. The problem is, that no matter how i try, the servo will turn only 180 degrees. So obviously i am making something wrong. If i write `myServo.write(0)` the servo rotates 180 degrees, and if i write `myServo.write(180)`, the servo rotates 180 degrees but in the other direction. How can i make it spin in only one direcvtion(360 degrees, more than 360 degrees)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally servos are not supposed to rotate continuously. However, now you can buy some "continuous rotation" servos that do. You can even transform your own servos into continuous (but this is not a super easy manipulation); check this link: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-modify-a-servo-motor-for-continuous-rotatio/

Comment: @jfpoilpret: thanks, but i think you misunderstand me. I can rotate the servo manually. So basicly it can be rotated continuasly, i just don't know how to code it. Or is there something else i need to do?

Comment: If this was a continuous servo, that would be indicated in the link you mentioned, and using Servo library would work with it, except that the value passed to `myServo.write()` would not specify an angle but a rotation speed, making it turn forever, until `myServo.write(90)`. The fact you can force it turn more than 360° does not mean it can do it programmatically.

Comment: @jfpoilpret: thank you! I thought if i can turn it around manually means that it is a continuous servo. So i have to solder and hopefully it will work then.